# Strange performance data instance Volume1#1 - what does it mean?

Tags: wmi, cluster-computing, hyper-v, windows-clustering

When I'm monitoring a Hyper-V cluster through WMI, the WMI performance provider provides one extra performance data for cluster shared volume instance named "Volume1#1". The original instance "Volume1" is no longer being updated with recent data.

[image: Screenshot of the instances]

What do these duplicate instances mean? Can there be more and if so, how do I determine which one contains recent data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this occurs when there happen to exist two instances with the same name. In this case, there were two filesystems called `Volume1`, so Windows renamed the second to `Volume1#1`. The fact that the first instance was not updated with new data was most likely a coincidence, there probably was no activity on `Volume1`.

It is not clear what information is used to map the first and second volume to their corresponding instances though, it might even be random.